# Environment variable not assigned

Tags: java

I am writing a small program in Java.

The Code is as follows:

```
public class Env {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String value;
    value = System.getenv("CPATH_1"); 
    if (value != null)  
        System.out.format("%s%n", value);
    else  
        System.out.format("Is not assigned.%n");
    value = System.getenv("CPATH_2"); 
    if (value != null)
        System.out.format("%s%n", value);
    else
        System.out.format("Is not assigned.%n");
    }
}
```

Both variables that are assigned exist in the System Environment Settings, but the messages are for both variables: "Is not assigned", i.e. "value" is "null" for both.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the problem but I think that it would be nice if you also mention the the OS which you are using to get better help. Like, I know that Linux is case sensitive while Windows might not be.

Comment: You are right: I use Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Use the other form of getenv(): it returns a map of all the environment variables.  Print them all out.  That will tell you if these are there, how they're spelled, etc.

Keep in mind that, if you define the variables in a command window, then run this program in a different window, it cannot find those definitions.  They must be defined globally before the program is run.

Comment: Thank you; I restarted the system and the problem was solved.

Comment: In this and in any StackOverflow question, 'accept' and perhaps upvote the answer if it solves your problem; that's how the reputations are established, and makes it more likely that future questions of yours will get attention.